# How can i block direct access of particular directory , files in Apache ?

Tags: html, css, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to block direct access of some directory , files with .htaccess in Ubuntu . I know that this question has many possible duplicates, but none of them helped me yet.

My directory structure :

```
---- /var/www/html 
                   - login.html
                   - private (folder) 
                       -- content.html
                       -- css / style1.css , style2.css
                       -- JS / myscript1.js , myscript.js
```

Now i want to block direct access of private folder . like

```
10.0.0.1/private - Block or Password required
10.0.0.1/private/css - Block or Password required
10.0.0.1/private/js - Block or Password required
```

But i need to access `css ,js` for `login.html` . So i want to allow these private folder access for `login.html` .

like :

```
 10.0.0.1/index.html - Allow 
 calling content.html via 10.0.0.1/index.html  - Allow 
 request private/css/style1.css via 10.0.0.1/index.html - Allow 
 request private/css/style2.css via 10.0.0.1/index.html - Allow
 request private/JS/myscript1.js via 10.0.0.1/index.html - Allow 
 request private/JS/myscript2.js via 10.0.0.1/index.html - Allow
```

I wrote like this to block private folder acess :

```
<Directory /var/www/html/private/>
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Restricted Content"
     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
     Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

This is working fine when i access   `10.0.0.1/private` . But this is making problem when `index.html` request `css , js` .

How can i done with `apache.conf` and `.htacess` ? How can i write rule ? 
 Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `.htaccess` file in each folder where you want to allow (eg: `private/css/.htaccess`)

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require

```
Satisfy Any
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

**Edit:**

> **Removing controls in subdirectories**
>
> The following example shows how to use the Satisfy directive to
>   disable access controls in a subdirectory of a protected directory.
>   This technique should be used with caution, because it will also
>   disable any access controls imposed by mod_authz_host.

```
<Directory /path/to/protected/>
Require user david
</Directory>
<Directory /path/to/protected/unprotected>
# All access controls and authentication are disabled
# in this directory
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: so should i keep my existing rule for  `/var/www/html/private/ ` also ?